# Where are the humans in Gears of War from?

Tags: gears-of-war

Are the humans native to Sera in the Gear's universe or are they from Earth (ruined or otherwise)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are native to Sera. Humans of Sera has no relation to earth, afaik. You can check this link for full storyline. [My link](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/26848/t793576-gears-of-war-storyline-universe/)

There are a couple novels explaining the complete background and the story in between two games, available on Amazon and other book retailers.